Changing ZFS partition reference to whole disk?
I'm not exactly sure how this happened, possibly a mistake on my part, but for some reason one of my disks in a pool is showing as whole_disk: 0 in the output for zdb – it seems that ZFS is treating it like I only added a single partition, but the disk itself was formatted by ZFS and contains no other partitions (besides EFI and GPT records).
This results in a setup that looks like the following:
zbackup:
    version: 5000
    name: 'zbackup'
    state: 0
    txg: 281069
    pool_guid: 9399051620538962852
    errata: 0
    hostid: 2895350363
    hostname: 'noname'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 9399051620538962852
        create_txg: 4
        com.klarasystems:vdev_zap_root: 129
        children[0]:
            type: 'raidz'
            id: 0
            guid: 13625876296773327015
            nparity: 2
            metaslab_array: 65
            metaslab_shift: 34
            ashift: 12
            asize: 32006194855936
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 130
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 4843865135278549537
                path: '/private/var/run/disk/by-id/media-8C6A7766-A56A-4442-B1C3-8E7639966428'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5984
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 131
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 11321776112851467303
                path: '/private/var/run/disk/by-id/media-1EE492E0-3C26-6B46-BD06-33BCE811B3B9'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5983
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 132
            children[2]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 2
                guid: 7516016376226480799
                path: '/private/var/run/disk/by-id/media-70E0A75E-9095-F04A-8D57-618A3FB99A85'
                whole_disk: 0
                DTL: 7762
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 7954

NOTE: There's a fourth entry omitted from the output to keep it a bit shorter (it's a resilver and is whole disk so not a problem).
However the disk was moved over from another pool, so ZFS should be fine to use it as an entire disk. I'm guessing I must have used the /by-id/media- identifier to add it, rather than the overall disk number, thinking this would be fine since that's how ZFS identifies the other disks under its control, but ZFS has treated it as me asking only for the specific partition that that identifier seems to reference, even though it's the ID ZFS was using internally for the old pool it was moved from.
Is there any way for me to convince ZFS to treat it as a whole disk without having to re-add it somehow (can I even use the disk to replace the partition)?
The output from zdb makes it seem like ZFS only cares about the /by-id/media- reference anyway, so as far as I can tell the only difference is that the third disk has whole_disk set to 0 instead of 1, is there any way to change that without a full resilver?
